FFmpeg Streaming Video SpringBoot endpoint not show video duration in video players
it turns out that I've been working on a personal project just out of curiosity.
the main function is to stream video by first encoding it through ffmpeg
then playback said video from any other device
call it "plex" very very primitive
although I achieve my goal which is to encode and send the video to the devices that make the request
this video is sent so to speak as a live broadcast.
I can only pause it, no forward or rewind, anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong or if I should take some other approach either in my service or controller?
I leave fragments of my code
THE CONTROLLER
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Log4j2
public class StreamController {

    @Autowired
    VideoStreamingService videoStreamingService;

    @Autowired
    VideoService videoService;


    @GetMapping("/stream/{videoId}")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> livestream(@PathVariable Long videoId,@RequestParam(required = false)  String codec) {
        Video video = videoService.findVideoById(videoId);
        if (video != null) {
            Codec codecEnum = Codec.fromString(codec);
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("video/mp4"))
                    .body(outputStream -> videoStreamingService.streamVideo(video.getPath(), outputStream,codecEnum));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}

THE SERVICE
@Service
public class VideoStreamingService {

    public void streamVideo(String videoPath, OutputStream outputStream, Codec codec) {

        FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.atPath()
                .addArguments("-i", videoPath)
                .addArguments("-b:v", "5000k")
                .addArguments("-maxrate", "5000k")
                .addArguments("-bufsize", "10000k")
                .addArguments("-c:a", "aac")
                .addArguments("-b:a", "320k")
                .addArguments("-movflags", "frag_keyframe+empty_moov+faststart")
                .addOutput(PipeOutput.pumpTo(outputStream)
                        .setFormat("mp4"))
                .addArgument("-nostdin");
        if (codec == Codec.AMD) {
            ffmpeg.addArguments("-profile:v", "high");
        }
        ffmpeg.addArguments("-c:v", codec.getFfmpegArgument());
        ffmpeg.execute();
    }
}

I have some enums to vary the encoding and use hardware acceleration or not.
and here is an example from my player
the endpoint is the following
http://localhost:8080/api/stream/2?codec=AMD
screenshot
I'm not sure if there's someone with more knowledge in either FFmpeg or Spring who could help me with this minor issue, I would greatly appreciate it. I've included the URL of the repository in case anyone would like to review it when answering my question
repo
I tried changing the encoding format.
I tried copying the metadata from the original video.
I tried sending a custom header.
None of this has worked.
I would like to achieve what is mentioned in many sites, which is when you load a video from the network, the player shows how much of that video you have in the local "buffer".

you encode video and create chunks of those for different resolutions, dash and hls are famous formats, you server index file to the client the client reads that index file and plays the chunks as specified

@silentsudo
interesting comment
I will see how to implement this format and the ranges you mentioned.
